# Provisioning a new schema from an existing one

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sharding

I have a template schema (dbo) in SqlServer 2008 R2 that we are using as a master schema for each customer's data.  How can I easily "copy" all of dbo's objects into a new schema?

`ALTER SCHEMA [target] TRANSFER [source].[objectname]` removes the original source object and I need it for future copies.

I do have a VSTSDB build process so I could take its output and find/replace on dbo, but that feels like the build process as opposed to a provisioning process.

Seems like this is typical process in the sharding world, yet I am not finding much in the way of tooling for this process.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [sqlcmd variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for the schema name and other values that are per-customer, then you just have to set the variables when you run your DDL scripts.

Comment: its looking like nothing built into sql server 2008 r2 assists with this task?

Comment: @BozoJoe I'm not sure what you mean: sqlcmd variables are built into SQL Server, or rather into the client tools for running SQL code, and this is one purpose they are intended for. There is no "copy schema" function, because what "copy" means is different in each case, e.g. does it include data? Or permissions?

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately there is no direct way. You can use this :

```
 SELECT 'ALTER SCHEMA NewSchema TRANSFER dbo.'+name
    FROM sys.objects
    WHERE type IN ('U','V','P','Fn')
    AND SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID) = 'dbo'
```

Comment: Your code moves objects from one schema to another, but the OP is asking about copying objects.